# Partner Community Pricebook restrict

Tags: community

I have created a salesforce community for partners using Visualforce page and Tabs.
When the user create an account he specifies the pricebook so when the Account is converted as partner and a contact is enabled as partner account user and the Partner user will be able to see only that account.
and my requirement is he should be able to see only the pricebook that was specified in the partner account.
But now he is able to see all the pricebooks that has the same product.
So how to restrict the access of other pricebook for the partner user. how to achieve the above requirement.

We have created a separate profile for the partner user.